# Regex to extract last period and md5 string

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression:

> /^[a-f0-9]{8}$/ --- This expression extracts an 8 character string as a **md5 hash**, for example: if I have the following string "hello world .305eef9f x1xxx 304ccf9f test1232" it will **return "304ccf9f"**

I also have the following regular expression:

> /.[^.]*$/ --- This expression extracts a string after the last period (included), for example, if I have "hello world.this.is.atest.case9.23919sd3xxxs" it will **return ".23919sd3xxxs"**

Thing is, I've readen a bit about regex but I can't join both expressions in order to find the md5 string after the last period (included), for example:

> topLeftLogo.93f02a9d.controller.99f06a7s ----> must **return ".99f06a7s"**

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: why should it return 304ccf9f ? md5 normally has a length of 32 characters. Can you rephrase your question a bit and give proper example of input and output

Comment: Your second regex already returns the correct value!

Comment: That's not an MD5 hash, it's just a hexadecimal string. And your first regex definitely won't extract the string you're claiming it will, the `^` at the beginning means it will only match at the start of the string. Even if it were not anchored, it wouldn't match the string you're claiming it would, it would match the **first** match which is `305eef9f` not `304ccf9f`.

Comment: It returns 304ccf9f because the regex is like that and its limited to 8 chars, you can check it here https://www.regextester.com with the same example. Second example doesn't returns the correct value because there is no restriction in what it's coming next to the period. Thing is I want to detect if a filename is hashed, because im doing some stuff with gulp-rev-all plugin, so in order to see if it is hashed I have to iterate through filenames like, for example: multiSelect.controller.11ce552c, typeInput.component.2a.b1b490ad and retrieve period and what comes after (.11ce552c and .b1b40ad)

Comment: @meagar please go to http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php and check that every hash matches with [a-f0-9] "hexadecimal" characters and matches every hashed string. If you have a better alternative to match it I'd be very happy if you share with us.

Comment: @PedroBezanilla Please post some code that does what you say it does. I don't need to open your website to generate a 32 character hexadecimal string to tell that `/^[a-f0-9]{8}$/` cannot match it. That pattern can match **exactly** 8 characters, no more, no less. And I encourage you to try running your own code. Try `"hello world .305eef9f x1xxx 304ccf9f test1232".match(/[a-f0-9]{8}/)` and tell me which string it matches; it won't be "304ccf9f"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `/^[a-f0-9]{8}$/` --- This expression extracts an 8 character string as a md5 hash

Yes but it doesn't return "304ccf9f" from "hello world .305eef9f x1xxx 304ccf9f test1232" because `^` in regex means start of string. How is it possible for it to match in middle of a string?

> `/.[^.]*$/` --- This expression extracts a string after the last period

No. It will do if you escape first dot only `\.`

To combine these two you have to replace `^` with `\.`:

`\.[a-f0-9]{8}$`

Answer (score 1):

To match your characters 8 times after the last dot in this range `[a-f0-9]` you might use (if supported) a positive lookahead `(?!.*\.)` to match your values and assert that what follows does not contain a dot:

`\.[a-f0-9]{8}(?!.*\.)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DRoNFS/1)

If you want to match characters from a-z instead of a-f like `99f06a7s` you could use `[a-z0-9]`

*About the first example*

This regex `^[a-f0-9]{8}$` will match one of the ranges in the character class 8 times from the start until the end of the string due to the anchors `^` and `$`. It would not find a match in `hello world .305eef9f x1xxx 304ccf9f test1232` on the same line.

*About the second example*

`.[^.]*$` will match any character zero or more times followed by matching not a dot. That would for example also match a single `a` and is not bound to first matching a dot because you have to escape the dot to match it literally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this just in case people needs to solve a similar casuistic:

> **Case 1:** for example, we want to get the hexadecimal ([a-f0-9]) 8 char string from our filename string
>   between the last period and the file extension, in order, for example, to remove that "hashed" part:

Example:

**file.name2222.controller.2567d667.js** ------> returns **.2567d667**

We will need to use the following regex:

`\.[a-f0-9]{8}(?=\.\w+$)`

> **Case 2:** for example, we want the same as above but ignoring the first period:

Example:

**file.name2222.controller.2567d667.js** ------> returns **2567d667**

We will need to use the following regex

`[a-f0-9]{8}(?=\.\w+$)`